# Poles and Zeros of this Bode Plot

Tags: plot

I would like to ask how to approximate the following on this plot. I am so confused about where to look:

[image: Bode Plot]

The poles, zeros, and the -3dB bandwidth frequency. Thank you.

Comment: you must look when the slope of the bode plot changes mainly so something is happening at 100 MhZ

I recommend you use the interactive demo available here https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Bode/BodeHow.html#demoConstant

Comment: That response has multiple poles-zeroes, it's not a simple lowpass. The phase is very wobbly, even starting with the low frequencies -- which means you're not showing everything, or that there is stuff happening before the 10 Hz mark.

Comment: Draw the asymptotes on the gain plot to reveal the dominant mode.